# JQuery: click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created this small 'modal'-form using bootstrap which looks a bit as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="H1">Create new Workflow</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
          ....
          <li class="list-group-itemCustom">
                 <input type="text" id="txtWorkflowAdmin" />
         </li>
          ...
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
           <button type="button" id="BtnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

The modals are stored in a separate aspx-page. I retrieve the modals using a ajax-call after which i bind the event-handlers:

```
function LoadModals() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Modalforms.aspx",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#Divmodals").html(data);
            SetModalEventtriggers();
        },
        error: function (xhr, errStatus, thrownError) {
            LogException(errStatus, thrownError, "LoadModals", []);
        }
    })
}

function  SetModalEventtriggers() {
        $("#txtWorkflowAdmin").blur(function () {
            CheckAdmin($(this));
        })

        $("#BtnSave").click(function () {
            SaveWorkflow();
        })
}
```

Those 2 events work perfectly independent. Example When i click the button (`BtnSave`) without `txtWorkflowAdmin` is focussed then the function `SaveWorkflow` gets executed.

Yet when my `txtWorkflowAdmin` is focussed and i click `BtnSave`. Then `.Click Function` isn't fired. The function of the `OnBlur` get executed though. When i click a second time on `BtnSave` then the `SaveWorkflow` is executed.

Why does this behavior occur? Am I missing some basic knowledge about Javascript-events?

**The Functions (Basic code supplied: errorhandling deeper code not included) :**

```
function SaveNewWorkflow() {

        ... (Check if other fields are filled in

        if (!CheckValidityUsername($("#txtWorkflowAdmin").val())) {
            $("#WorkflowAdminErrorMessage").css("display", "block");
            return;
        }

        ... (If all fields are filled in => This piece of code is never reached when   txtWorkflowAdmin is focussed)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Actions.aspx",
            data: outerJsonData,
            success: function () {
               ... Do some actions here. 
           }}) 
 }

function CheckAdmin(txtAdmin) {
    // Show/Hide errormessage
    if (!CheckValidityUsername(txtAdmin.val())) {
        btnClicked.closest("li").prev().css("display", "block");
    }
    else {
        btnClicked.closest("li").prev().css("display", "none");
    }
}


function CheckValidityUsername(userName) {
    var validUser = true;
    var jsonData = { action: "CheckUsername",
            SidUser: userName,
            Docbase: docbase
        };

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        url: "Search.aspx",
        data: jsonData,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            validUser = obj.ValidUser;
            return validUser;
        },
        error: function (xhr, errStatus, thrownError) {
            LogException(errStatus, thrownError, "CheckValidityUsername", jsonData);
        }
    })

    return validUser;
}
```

Thanx to anyone who was helping me! Thanks to you guys, the problem was quickly resolved!

Comment: might be a good idea to include the code of those functions? maybe some of it is interfering with the click event in some way or another...

Comment: It is working here http://jsfiddle.net/3Ch5u/

Comment: I'll include the most basic code behind the function (not all). As it would be too much

Comment: The modals are stored in a separate aspx-page. After the ajax-call to that aspx-page (GET) is completed then I bind the events to the controls. i'll add it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of click try with `mousedown`:

```
$("#BtnSave").mousedown(function () {
    SaveWorkflow();
});
```

Because `blur` is getting fired before click.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Jgfr/)

---

*Why does this behavior occur?*

See when you `click/focus` on `$("#txtWorkflowAdmin")` button then this button gets the foucs and as you have bound a `blur` event to it, `.blur()` always gets fired first against click. you can see the below two lines what is happening and what you can do here:

1. `click` event works when you release the left mouse button.
2. while `mousedown` only looks for a push of left mouse button.

---

As @webeno commented this is another fiddle to checkout that `mousedown` is working first:

### [Demo @ fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Jgfr/2/)

---

Although this can also be done with a `setTimeout()` method:

```
function CheckAdmin(txtAdmin) {
  setTimeout(function(){
     // Show/Hide errormessage
     if (!CheckValidityUsername(txtAdmin.val())) {
       btnClicked.closest("li").prev().css("display", "block");
     } else {
       btnClicked.closest("li").prev().css("display", "none");
     }
  }, 1000);
}
```

---

### [Demo with setTimeout() method](http://jsfiddle.net/2Jgfr/3/)

Comment: @C-link because i think click happens when you release the left mouse button while mousedown only looks for pushing the left button.

Comment: your solution will only work for alert, try a text() and it will be different http://jsfiddle.net/2Jgfr/1/

Comment: sorry, it's still not working, the first function is supposed to output what you add into the field but it doesn't, it still only triggers the 2nd function, ie. the alert...

Comment: @webeno yeah just got it where it is failing i think this needs a timeout function. not sure but can be tested.

Comment: Anyhow it seem to be compatible with my code. So i'm quite happy. The mousedown did apparently resolve my problem. Although the order of executing may have changed, this has no impact at all to the correct flow inside my web application. Cheers Mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try using preventDefault:

```
$("#BtnSave").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        SaveWorkflow();
    })
```

**Update:**

I think this should work:

```
$("#BtnSave").click(function () {
    CheckAdmin($("#txtWorkflowAdmin"));
    SaveWorkflow();
})
```

Comment: why preventDefault? he is telling as, the event handler itself is not firing right?

Comment: Something preventing to click so using preventDefault might help.

Comment: OP has clearly mentioned `click` is not firing when you first click the `$("#txtWorkflowAdmin")` so now focus is on this button when you click on `$("#BtnSave")`, blur event fired first. `mousedown` will work here.

Comment: @Jai as i commented under your answer, `mousedown` only works with `alert` apparently...

Comment: @webeno i just comment against your comment with a fiddle to test.